# Copy from one temp table to another temp table on condition base?

Tags: sql

How to copy from one temp table to another temp table on condition base then how to retrieve from that pasted table?

I tried like below but retrieving from both conditions where as I want pasted table data selection which I never getting.

```
alter procedure Get_LoginLogutDetails 
as 
begin 
DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @cmdOriginal AS NVARCHAR(max) 
CREATE TABLE #result 
( 
LoggedOutTime   datetime 
)   

CREATE TABLE #OriginalResult 
( 
Duration    varchar(100) 
) 

declare @loggedOutTime     varchar(20) 


SET @cmd ='select LoggedOutTime from LastLoggedInDetails' 
Insert into #result 
EXEC(@cmd) 

declare result_cursor cursor for 
SELECT LoggedOutTime 
from  #result 
where LoggedOutTime is null 

OPEN result_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @loggedOutTime 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0      
BEGIN   


if(@loggedOutTime is null) 
begin   

select 'Running..' 
Insert into #OriginalResult 
EXEC(@cmd) 
end 

else if(@loggedOutTime is not null) 
begin 

select LoggedOutTime from #result 
Insert into #OriginalResult 
EXEC(@cmd) 
end 


FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @loggedOutTime 
END 

select * from #OriginalResult 
end
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. That doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.

Comment: Please try to explain at a higher level what you are trying to accomplish. Generally using cursors is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i had a read through your script and have tried to work out what you are trying to do. it looks like you are possibly trying to get the LoggedOutTimes when there is a time, if there is no logged out time, you want the result "Running..." to be inserted into a temp table.

```
SELECT     ISNULL(LoggedOutTime, 'Running...')
INTO       #OriginalResult
FROM       LastLoggedInDetails
```

This gives you a temp table with the above scenario. Unsure on the datatype of LoggedOutTime, you may need to convert it to an nvarchar.

Your original question doesn't make a lot of sense, you should try rewording it to get some more accurate help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all for my not good explainations , but I finally reached my need.
I want like nelow.

```
select LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime,case 

when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is not null then CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (hour,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime ))+' Hours '+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (minute,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime )%60) +' Minutes' 

when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is null then 'Running...'
end
from dbo.LastLoggedInDetails
```